# dots to geometry shapes transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking for the name of the transformation, but i didn't make it here is a 
[website that shows the animation](http://www.berengereaudo.fr/).
Would you please provide me with the exact name of the transformation or how to do such thing

Comment: Looks like a `<canvas>` animation made using javascript.

Comment: The exact script being used can easily be determined by looking at the source code of that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Constellation you can Google it and you will found some ready code out there